# Como faço para unir dois resultados de uma query?

Tags: c#, sql, .net, ado.net

Estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação em C# e gostaria de saber como faço para unir dois resultados de duas *queries* SQL em uma só. Tenho o seguinte código:

```cs
public List<MalaDireta> ObterMalaDireta()
{    
    List<MalaDireta> resultado = new List<MalaDireta>();

    string sql_funcionario = "select id, nome, email from funcionario";
    string sql_fornecedor = "select id, nome, email from fornecedor";

    var conexao = new SqlConnection("string de conexão");

    var comando = new SqlCommand(sql_funcionario, conexao);

    try
    {
       conexao.Open();

       // como eu monto meu comando com as duas queries?

       var dataReader = comando.ExecuteReader();
       while (dataReader.Read())
       {
          MalaDireta m = new MalaDireta();
          m.Nome = dataReader["nome"];
          m.Email = dataReader["email"];

          resultado.Add(m);
       }
    }
    catch
    {
    }
    finally
    {
       conexao.Close();
    }

    return resultado;
}
```

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Que tal fazer a união através da própria query sql usando o [UNION](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_union.asp):

```
select id, nome, email from funcionario
union
select id, nome, email from fornecedor
```

No seu caso ficaria assim:

```
string sql_todos = "select id, nome, email from funcionario " +
                   "union "+
                   "select id, nome, email from fornecedor";
```

Answer (score 13):

A resposta do @Ecil está adequada, mas acrescento o uso do `UNION ALL`.

Qual a diferença entre `UNION` e `UNION ALL`?

- `UNION` faz uma espécie de `DISTINCT`, inibindo resultados repetidos
- `UNION ALL` traz todos os resultados, mesmo os com valores repetidos

Existe alguma vantagem no `UNION ALL`? Em tese, ele é mais eficiente por não aplicar o `DISTINCT`, isto é, não fazendo  comparação dos valores dos registros.

Então basta uma mudança simples:

```
string sql_todos = "select id, nome, email from funcionario " +
               "union all "+
               "select id, nome, email from fornecedor";
```

Este conceito se aplica, pelo menos, ao SQL Server, Oracle, MySQL e PostgreSQL.

Comment: Boa observação. Só acrescento que a escolha entre UNION e UNION ALL depende do resultado que se quer (a pergunta não deixa isso claro).

Comment: Concordo com o @utluiz, boa observação. Neste caso, porém, é bem pouco provável que funcionários também sejam fornecedores e mesmo o sendo, provavelmente teriam id's e emails diferentes.

Answer (score 8):

Em teoria, basta você repetir o processo de reabrir a conexão, executar a outra query, e passar pelo laço de repetição adicionando os resultados da sua segunda query.

```
string sql_funcionario = "select id, nome, email from funcionario";
string sql_fornecedor = "select id, nome, email from fornecedor";

var conexao = new SqlConnection("string de conexão");


MalaDireta m = new MalaDireta();
var comando = new SqlCommand(sql_funcionario, conexao);

try
{
   conexao.Open();

   // como eu monto meu comando com as duas queries?

   var dataReader = comando.ExecuteReader();
   while (dataReader.Read())
   {

      m.Nome = dataReader["nome"];
      m.Email = dataReader["email"];

      resultado.Add(m);
   }
}
catch
{
}
finally
{
   conexao.Close();
}

var comando = new SqlCommand(sql_fornecedor, conexao);

try
{
   conexao.Open();

   // como eu monto meu comando com as duas queries?

   var dataReader = comando.ExecuteReader();
   while (dataReader.Read())
   {

      m.Nome = dataReader["nome"];
      m.Email = dataReader["email"];

      resultado.Add(m);
   }
}
catch
{
}
finally
{
   conexao.Close();
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Existem duas formas:

1. Se a estrutura das suas queries forem as mesmas você pode usar um UNION:

`var query = "select id, nome, email from funcionario union select id, nome, email from fornecedor";`

1. Você pode enviar as duas queries no mesmo SqlCommand. A Classe DataReader suporta nativamente múltiplos resultados usando o método `dataReader.NextResult()`:

   ```
       var comando = new SqlCommand(string.Concat(sql_funcionario, ";", sql_fornecedor), conexao);
       var dataReader = comando.ExecuteReader();
       while (dataReader.NextResult()) {
           while (dataReader.Read()) {
               MalaDireta m = new MalaDireta();
               m.Nome = dataReader["nome"];
               m.Email = dataReader["email"];

               resultado.Add(m);
           }
       }
   ```

Answer (score 2):

Caro, mesmo que alguma mágica oculta possa ser feita para unir os dois readers para readibilidade eu só vejo duas opções:

1. Põe um union na query e coloca a business logic pro lado do banco. (meio feio)
2. Pega os dois readers (converte pra Enumerable da entidade) e faz um merge com Linq, pode escrever uns Unit Tests para fazer o codigo responsável

Comment: você poderia me dar um exemplo em código de como seria o `union` ?

Comment: Não é necessário converter os readers para IEnumerable, basta usar o método NextResult() do datareader.

Comment: Faz isso não querido, isso vai de encontro com "mágica oculta" que eu mencionei. Conta 3 meses e outro desenvolvedor e isso vai virar código perigoso. Quando eu mencionei os Enumerables, me refiro aos retornos dos repositórios que ele vai ter. Esse exemplo simplificado o Union resolve, mas se expandir uma vírgula vai aparecer DAL fazendo query pra dois repositórios e confundindo conceito.